# Apple Script: Activating menu that only appears after button click

Tags: automation, user-interface, applescript

I am trying to export all of my recipes in Paprika Recipe Manager one by one. Paprika's bulk export feature bundles them all into 1 file which is not what I need.

My code below successfully clicks the "More Actions" button, making the "More Actions" menu appear but then I am stuck. How can I make Applescript click the "Export" button?

Screenshot of hierarchy and the button and menu in question

[image]

```
try
    tell application "Paprika Recipe Manager"
        activate
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Paprika Recipe Manager"
            --click menu item "Edit" of menu "Connections" of menu bar 1
            click button "More Actions" of window "All-Butter Pie Crust"

            tell menu "More Actions" of button "More Actions"
                click menu item "Export"
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    return true
on error error_message
    return false
end try
```

Comment: Please elaborate how you are stuck

Comment: @LPChip I realize now my question wasn't very clear. Clarified. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I'm not sure you can `tell menu`. These things usually go `click menu item "Fred" of menu 1 of menu item "Barney" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Wilma" of menu bar 1` which I usually manage to figure out using [UIElementInspector](http://download.freedownloadmanager.org/Mac-OS/UIElementInspector/FREE-1.4.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Code:

```
tell application "Paprika Recipe Manager"
    activate
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Paprika Recipe Manager"
        tell window 1
            tell button 4
                click
                tell menu 1
                    --PRESS ARROW DOWN 3 TIMES
                    key code 125
                    key code 125
                    key code 125
                    --PRESS ENTER KEY
                    key code 36
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```